# rake db:test:prepare not creating all tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

NOTE: Using Rails 3.0.7, Postgresql 8.4.4-1, rake 0.8.7.

Trying to get rails testing working.

The command rake db:test:prepare appears to work fine --

```
$ rake db:test:prepare -t
(in /home/beau/looked)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "slugs_id_seq" for serial column "slugs.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "slugs_pkey" for table "slugs"
```

BUT some of the tables are not being created.

These are the "development" tables:

```
$ psql -d looked -U admin -c '\d'

               List of relations
 Schema |       Name        |   Type   | Owner 
--------+-------------------+----------+-------
 public | businesses        | table    | admin
 public | businesses_id_seq | sequence | admin
 public | categories        | table    | admin
 public | categories_id_seq | sequence | admin
 public | schema_migrations | table    | admin
 public | slugs             | table    | admin
 public | slugs_id_seq      | sequence | admin
(7 rows)
```

Tables created by rake:db:prepare for the test environment --

```
$ psql -d looked_test -U admin -c '\d'
               List of relations
 Schema |       Name        |   Type   | Owner
--------+-------------------+----------+-------
 public | categories        | table    | admin
 public | schema_migrations | table    | admin
 public | slugs             | table    | admin
 public | slugs_id_seq      | sequence | admin
(4 rows)
```

As you can see it has created some tables, but not businesses, businesses_id_seq or categories_id_seq.

I'm at a loss as to why, can someone help me?

Comment: What does your schema file look like? `RAILS_ROOT/db/schema.rb`

Comment: What's your `schema.rb` file look like?

Comment: OK I just checked and the tables are somehow missing from the schema file.

Comment: It was my last migration. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First make sure to run `rake db:migrate` before `rake db:test:prepare`.

If that doesn't work, back up your `schema.rb` somewhere, remove it, then run `rake db:schema:dump` before running `rake db:test:prepare`. That will make sure your `schema.rb` file fully reflects your database.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the schema.rb file by rolling back the last migration. Not sure what's wrong with that migration, though. If I can't figure it out I'll ask another question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. As I can see now, a merge reverted some changes in my schema.rb which caused the trouble. BTW: Removing schema.rb has not been necessary.