# Factory girl not registering user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have looked at other topics and did a Google search, none of the solutions works unfortunately. I have just started writing my first tests for password reset. I should be receiving a Capybara elementnotfound error for no link with title or text "password". Instead factory girl is saying its not a registered user.

```
  1) PasswordResets emails user when requesting password reset
     Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: user
     # ./spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's my password_reset_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "PasswordResets" do
  it "emails user when requesting password reset"
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit login_path
    click_link "password"
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    click_button "Reset Password"
  end
```

factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  f.sequence :email do |n| "foo#{n}@example.com"
  end
  f.password "secret"
end
end
```

gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect in your factory declaration, I would go with something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
    password "secret"
  end
end
```

Comment: I still receive the same error: Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find': Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)

Comment: Try replacing `gem 'factory_girl'` by `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` in your `Gemfile`

Comment: I changed that prior to posting here. It produced a different error, " Mysql2::Error: Table 'dating_test.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users` (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)"

Comment: So it seems that your test db doesn't exist. You can run `rake db:migrate` and then `rake db:test:prepare`. If that doesn't work, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869542/rake-dbtestprepare-not-creating-all-tables

Comment: Your last comment fixed the issue. I had to delete some previous migrations then it allowed me to run rake db:migrate. Thank you